Vue 3 v-for local variable
I am using vue-3 have the following problem:
My app holds a list of chapters, and each one its sections:
[
  {
    "title":"Chapter 1",
    "sections":[
      {
        "title":"Section 1",
        "numPages":14
      },
      {
        "title":"Section 2",
        "numPages":8
      },
      {
        "title":"Section 3",
        "numPages":12
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title":"Chapter 2",
    "sections":[
      {
        "title":"Section 1",
        "numPages":5
      },
      {
        "title":"Section 2",
        "numPages":7
      }
    ]
  }
]

I need to print it in the following format:
Chapter 1
   Section 1     1 - 14
   Section 2     15 - 22
   Section 3     23 - 34
Chapter 2
   Section 1     35 - 40
   Section 2     41 - 47

In other words, for each chapter I need to print the range of pages, using this formula:
// init
lastToPage = 1

// each section
fromPage = lastToPage + 1
toPage = lastToPage numPages
lastToPage = toPage

The question:
Is there a way to have an accumulator variable inside v-for loop? (in order to keep lastToPage value)
Any other better solution?

Maybe this can help: https://vuejs.org/examples/#tree

Don't see how this relates to my problem....

inside v-for loop what v-for loop? wouldn't there be nested v-for loops? The way I would do it is to have a computed that adds to each section the starting page for that section

^^ or, you can update the data in place like data.reduce((acc, chapter) =>   chapter.sections.reduce((acc, section) =>  (section.startingPage = acc, acc + section.numPages), acc), 1);

Following suggestion of @Jaromanda, I came with this solution.
In the template I replaced:
<template v-for="chapter in chapters">

with:
<template v-for="chapter in extendedChapters">

And added a computed variable extendedChapters:
const extendedChapters = computed(() => {
  let extendedChapters = chapters.value
  extendedChapters.reduce(
      (acc, chapter) => chapter['events'].reduce((acc, event) => (event.firstPage = acc, acc + event['numPages']), acc), 1
  );
  return extendedChapters
})

